# systemd service ends up in “inactive (dead)” after boot

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd-unit

I have added my service to **systemd** (I am running it on a **pi3**), it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Oral-B BLE scanner service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
StartLimitBurst=10
StartLimitIntervalSec=10
Requires=bluetooth.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/scripts
ExecStart=/home/pi/scripts/scanOralB.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

I have added a symbolic link to the above file in */lib/systemd/system*. I have enabled the service as well. Just to be sure I checked.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl is-enabled scanOralB.service
enabled
```

If I reboot and check the status it looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status scanOralB.service
* scanOralB.service - Oral-B BLE scanner service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/pi/scripts/scanOralB.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

If I start the service manually it works just fine. Can someone explain why the service is not being started after boot? I get no extra output from *journalctl* either.

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl enable scanOralB.service` instead of add symbolic link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not being started because it's not wanted by anything that gets started.

> ```
> [Install]
> WantedBy=network-online.target
> ```
>
> I have added a symbolic link to the above file in */lib/systemd/system*.

Pretty much all of that is wrong.

- The unit file should be *placed* in `/etc/systemd/system`.  Symbolic links are interpreted idiosyncratically by systemd, and do not have the conventional filesystem semantics.  And `/lib/systemd/system` is not the place for hand-written unit files that do not come from packages.
- The unit file should be wanted by something that actually gets started at bootstrap.  `network-online.target` usually does not.  `multi-user.target` is the usual choice.  `graphical.target` is another.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I actually managed to solve this myself, changing to graphical.target but the location really did not matter, at least not for me. also the fact of it being a symlink or actual file did not seem to matter either.

Comment: Where are you supposed to put service files that don't originate in a package?